# How would you save a thumbnail of a video to be placed in a CollectionView

Tags: iphone, video, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionview

I am working on an application that records a "videos", and save it to a folder in the documents directory. I was wondering how I would go about obtaining a thumbnail like in Photo's application. So that when the user clicks on it, I will play a video in full screen.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You're basically asking how to create a thumbnail image from a video?

Comment: Yes i am asking that exact question :/ Sorry for being long winded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
movie.shouldAutoplay = NO;
UIImage *image = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[movie release];
```